# geoserver JVM settings

Tags: jvm, geoserver

I want to change the heap space of my JVM for GeoServer 2.11 running on WindowsServer 2012. In [this SO answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/224400/67394) and [this post](http://www.dixis.com/?p=713) it is stated that the `\Geoserver xxx\wrapper\wrapper.conf` file needs to be changed accordingly. However I don't have a `\wrapper\` folder or a `wrapper.conf` file in my GeoServer directory

How can I change the [recommended settings](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html) for GeoServer?

Comment: how did you install GeoServer?

Comment: Using the [Windows Installer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html) with the "run manually" option.

Comment: @iant is there something I can change with the installation?

Comment: I'm not a windows user so I can't really help

Comment: @iant i solved this issue but created another one. Maybe you can have a look at this [SE question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743687/geoserver-2-11-as-windows-service-with-controlflow-extension) or forward it to someone?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled GeoServer "as a Service" as explained in [step 14](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html) and then `/wrapper/wrapper.conf` is available

Comment: but this in turn does not work with the Control Flow extension. [SE question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743687/geoserver-2-11-as-windows-service-with-controlflow-extension)