# geoserver 2.11 as windows service with controlflow extension

Tags: java, geoserver, control-flow

I'm trying to set up GeoServer for a production environment. I have installed GeoServer using the [Windows Installer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html) as a Service in Windows Services.

I tried to add the [Control Flow Module](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/controlflow/index.html) but then GeoServer won't start up anymore. A sample of the log file below.

If I remove the Control Flow Module GeoServer starts up normally again.
The control flow plugin works if I install GeoServer with the "run manually" option.

Any ideas on how to get the Control Flow Module to work under a service installation?

`2017-05-02 18:39:34,859 WARN [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.11.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.11.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.11.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.11.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.11.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.11.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.11.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.11.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-05-02 18:39:34,859 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-05-02 18:39:34,859 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed`

Comment: this sort of question is probably better asked on the geoserver users list

Comment: [did already](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Control-flow-with-GeoServer-as-a-windows-service-td5319165.html)

Comment: Did you try it using linux? much more likely to work there

Comment: i wish I could. Unfortunately I'm not the one choosing the OS